# How do we leave space or box for students' comments?

Tags: moodle, r-exams

How do we leave a space for students to write the comments after each question when we use **exams** package? Is there any example or template to see how this can be done? We use Moodle as a learning management system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such functionality has been added in version 2.4-0 of the package in `exams2moodle()`. This allows you to do:

```
library("exams")
exams2moodle("essayreg.Rmd")
```

This includes both a text box and a file upload option below the text. See the exercise file for details in the meta-information: http://www.R-exams.org/templates/essayreg/. We are planning to streamline these options in the future, though, in order to have a single set of options in R/exams for different learning management systems.

We also started working on allowing some text entry as part of "cloze" question. However, Moodle does not seem to have an "essay" options for this question type, see: https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Embedded_Answers_(Cloze)_question_type. Hence, the best we could do at the moment is a single line text entry, see:

```
exams2moodle("essayreg2.Rmd")
```

Comment: Many thanks, Achim. I will try this version with a given meta information.